# JQuery - Get css property within selector

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set a custom attribute to the target element's CSS property (font-size). How do I access the css from within a selector like:

```
$('.font-900').attr('data-resfont', <font-size here>);
```

I tried:

```
$('.font-900').attr('data-resfont', this.css('font-size'));
```

I'm guessing this will not work as 'this' refers to the attr function. My next step was:

```
$('.font-900').attr('data-resfont', this.target.css('font-size'));
```

This doesn't seem to work either. I think I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function as the second argument to `.attr` which is iterated over each element in the collection (you cannot do this with `.data` or I would have suggested using that).

```
$(".font-900").attr('data-resfont', function () {
    return this.style.fontSize;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

- Iterate over every element that matches:

```js
$('.font-900').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-resfont', $(this).attr('font-size'))
});
```

- Create a variable assignment:

```js
var e = $('.font-900');
e.css('data-resfont', e.attr('font-size');
```

- Use function to set the attribute

```js
$(".font-900").attr('data-resfont', function () {
   return this.style.fontSize;
});
```

Comment: That's a perfect answer but someone beat you to the solution I was looking for. Its only fair to accept their answer. I'd vote you up if I could!

Comment: Wjouldn't that be `.each` instead of `.forEach`?